# force.com ISV development, deployment, support

Tags: salesforce, force.com

We're an ISV that's completed our first app on force.com. It's an xRM-like app with extended workflow to build out complex campaigns (not simple marketing-like campaigns) and integration with on-premise software. The platform brings enormous value, and at the same time some challenges. Interested in other ISV experiences around the following:

1. Application upgrade process. Customers expect cloud app upgrade to "just happen". Reality is that there's inevitable manual pre- and post-upgrade steps that can fill many pages. We don't want to burden the customer with this, and at the same time while we're happy to do the upgrade work for the customer, we don't want access to customer data and the need for elaborate security assurances that come along with that access. A conundrum.
2. Development environment. Agile/scrum development relies on achieving full test automation and continuous integration, yet full automation beyond unit test seems difficult or impossible.
3. Background processing. Constraints on scheduled jobs, callouts, and futures, and issues with transaction management present challenges to traditional software development.

Curious what other ISVs have found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am now working at my second Force.com ISV and so have a fair amount of experience in releasing products on the platform (have seen 4 separate products releases, 1 which included 3 version releases and 1 including another version update).

1. If possible, you should try to remove any pre/post install steps that the user requires to do. It sounds tough, and it is, but its the biggest reason people don't adopt a product. The idea is that it is quick and easy to install, one click, and any extra effort detracts from the user experience. Ensuring your system is data independent is a good way of getting around the data security issues you referred to, and obviously you can offer a consultancy to do the upgrade work. A sensible idea might be to have a list of all the objects and fields that are affected by your products installation and then to do a check of the customer org before installing. I would also say that installing in sandbox and doing a couple of weeks user testing can highlight any problems you may have in future very effectively.
2. It is not true that full test automation beyond unit tests cannot occur and is actually very simple. The key is having the necessary framework setup. So you would have a central version control system where your code is stored (a key agile part). Then you create a script so that when code is committed, it runs an install on a SFDC org, running all tests and reporting back. You can then get this script to run a set of apex classes or upload a bunch of CSV files to put data in with either further fuller apex tests to run functionality or selenium running to do a set of tests. You can then also use this test data and script for knocking out demo environments for sales guys.
3. The governor and background processing limits are a bit tight, but they keep on being increased. Maybe you should integrate with Heroku or similar to do some larger external processing? I will say though I think it improves programming abilities in general, making you think about what it is your doing and the best way to do it. This then leads to a more pleasant end user experience. Batch apex jobs area a good way of doing this processing and you can use the asyncapexjob object to report back on the status f a run to users.

Hope that helps and gives you a different perspective!

Paul